# AngularJS custom directive not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have created a custom directive in an app.js file:

```
app.directive('productDescription', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'product-description.html'
    };
});
```

This is the contents of the product-description.html file:

```
<div>
    <h4>Description</h4>
    <blockquote>{{product.description}}</blockquote>
</div>
```

And here is how I've referred to it in my index.html file:

```
<product-description class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)">
</product-description>
```

However the template is not showing on the webpage, can anyone find any mistakes with the above code?

**EDIT:**

I already have the controller for the ng-show attribute, this was working fine before I added the custom directive:

```
app.controller('PanelController', function(){
    var panel = this;
    panel.tab = 1;

    panel.selectTab = function(setTab) {
        panel.tab = setTab;
    };
    panel.isSelected = function(checkTab){
        return panel.tab === checkTab;
    };
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

Just checked the console and the error shows:

> angular.min.js:108 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/damonmorris/Documents/ProgrammingProjects/lilysKitchen/LKCB/product-description.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

can anyone explain the problem here?

Comment: check console.what is the error?

Comment: what's that `ng-show` !! do you send it from controller?

Comment: where is your `product-description.html` template? i mean the full url! this error because you can't access to your html change the url

Comment: do you use `localhost` server?

Comment: use update answer and tell me the result of it